# How to use performance.now() to do faster setinterval

Tags: setinterval

How to use performance.now() to do faster setinterval

```
setInterval(function () { // Content value
            ...
        }, 1);
```

i want to do this faster than 1 millisecond

Comment: Running things multiple times per millisecond is almost definitely a bad idea.

Comment: while(true) ? or try placing `0.001`

Comment: "while" is true ahead , i want to replace less than 1 millisecond overthere with performance method or (  process.hrtime() from nodejs )

Comment: You should not do that.

Comment: how can i do to do this ? please explain ...

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the first place.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want to use it in my project with lower than millisecond , i need to use setinterval with lower than millisecond , and JavaScript have performance.now() method to do this . of course nodejs had  process.hrtime() and both of them can use for lower than millisecond , but i dont know how can i use it in setinterval to get lower than millisecond result